# Tv out with iOS 4 and 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-privateapi, iphone-3gs

Is there a method to display the screen of an iPhone 3GS with iOS4 on a TV using the TVout cable?
I succeed to do it with an iPhone 4 using public framework. I know 3GS doesn't support this feature with public framework.

How to do it with private framework?